# Toggling layers with the Layer Control widget swipe option

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I've been playing with the Layer Control Widget's swipe option, and I'm wondering if there is a way to toggle between two different layers, one on either side of the swipe bar.  I working with two different versions of the FEMA FIRM data and want to be able to use the swipe to compare between them.

Answer (score 1):

Trae,

The swipe capability in Layer Control uses Esri JSAPI [Layer Swipe](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/layerswipe-amd.html) widget. It currently doesn't have that ability. Looks like someone has made a similar request [here](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-dijit-layer-swipe-js/issues/10). You might +1 the idea and explain your need.